# Putting data from html into a google sheet

Tags: http, google-apps-script

I am trying to pull the clock data from https://www.time.gov/ as a test for a script for a larger program, and I can't figure out  how to get the actual clock data to display in sheets.

```
function datapuller() {
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.time.gov/').getContentText();
  var text = page.match('lzswftext');
}
```

It works according to the script editor, but the data doesn't display in sheets...

Comment: Why?  What's wrong with Date()?  By the time the url responds and the script performs its function, time has passed and the time is no longer current.

Comment: Try `Logger.log(page);` and look at the output of `getContentText()`. See if you can find the 'lzswftext' in there. They probably call an API somewhere to get that data after the page loads.

Comment: TheWizEd its just a test, I'm actually using the script to get order data for products from a website. I went with time.gov because there isn't much going on with the site.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the text returned by `getContentText()` doesnt return the page as you expected. The page must load data after the initial `fetch()` with the data you are looking for.

After pulling open Chrome network tools (F12) and looking at the network requests I spotted a call to `https://www.time.gov/actualtime.cgi?__lzbc__=cytoln`. This returns an xml with a timestamp value.

This should be helpful:

```
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.time.gov/actualtime.cgi?__lzbc__=cytoln').getContentText();
var xml = XmlService.parse(page);
var timestamp = xml.getRootElement().getAttribute("time").getValue();

Logger.log(timestamp); //seems to return a timestamp in *microseconds*

var dateObj = new Date(timestamp/1000); //something like this to get Date obj?
Logger.log(dateObj.toUTCString());
```